# sed issue: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, opencv, sed, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to run this command:

```
 sed -i ‘s/if (DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/g’ makefiles/cmake/arm-linux.cmake
```

But it seems my bash syntax is messed up when I copy that snippet from http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-2-compilation/ and I get this:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any idea why?

Comment: When I change both apostrophes into backticks I get this:

    -bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `DEFINED'
    -bash: command substitution: line 1: `s/if (DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `m'

Comment: Seems like you are using a mac. If so, then put empty quotes around the `-i` like `-i""`.

Comment: @huertanix: Not backticks. Apostrophes. What you have now are neither apostrophes nor backticks.

Comment: BTW, this error is mentioned in the first comment on the original posting, and the second has a pointer to the solution.

Comment: The second comment there points to a forum that no longer has the solution alluded to. I ended up manually doing a substitution in vim, which worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i ‘
#      ^ a problem
```

This is a “smart quote” of sorts, U+2018. Use a regular apostrophe instead, `'`. Same for the closing quote.